# How to remove characters in a field javascript

Tags: javascript, decimalformat

I tried using the following code to format a text field value from `(N50,000.00 NGN)` to `(50000)` but the result instead of producing `50000` is producing `5000000`.

Can someone please help?

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    function doWork() {
        var amount = document.getElementsByName('amount');
        var str = amount[0].value;
        var temp = '';
        for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
            if (!isNaN(str[i]))
                temp += str[i];
        }
        amount[0].value = temp;
    }
</script>

<input type="text" name="amount" value="N50,000.00 NGN" />
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="doWork();">
```

Comment: You strip out every character which is not a number. This also strips of the ".", so left is 5000000.

Comment: You're only testing NaN, but after the decimal there's still more numbers.  A regex may be more appropriate here, but to do so you'd have to define all the types of inputs you're expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method to get what you want might be to just add another condition in your for loop:

```
if (str[i] === '.')
    break;
```

Comment: I don't know if at any point the digits to the right of the decimal become significant digits.  At which point, you may be better off keeping the decimal in the final product rather than stopping at it.  Though, strictly speaking from the question, this seems the simplest solution.

Comment: @user1169578, I agree with you that this is not the best solution. You're also checking every string position for a period, which is also unnecessary if you know what string format you're expecting. I think regex would be a better option as you mentioned in your comment, but given what the OP already has I think this is the easiest and quickest extension. If you're iterating through everything character in the string, it's already going to be difficult to add more logic as the requirements become more complex.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at the value you are trying to format.

In `N50,000.00 NGN` all digits are *not NaN*. So your result is 5000000 (`50 000 00`). The solution is to stop at dot symbol, e.g.

```
function doWork() {
    var amount = document.getElementsByName('amount');
    var str = amount[0].value;
    var temp = '';
    for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (str[i] === '.') break; // there it is
        if (!isNaN(str[i]))
            temp += str[i];
    }
    amount[0].value = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it with a regex.  Note, that if the user has multiple decimal points in the input field it may act oddly.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    function doWork() {
        var amount = document.getElementsByName('amount');
        amount[0].value = amount[0].value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");
        amount[0].value = amount[0].value.replace(/[.][0-9]*/g, "");
    }
</script>

<input type="text" name="amount" value="N50,000.00 NGN" />
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="doWork();">
```

The first line removes all characters except numbers and decimal points.
The second, removes all decimal points and any numbers to the right of them.

Using parseInt and toFixed may be better, though:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    function doWork() {
        var amount = document.getElementsByName('amount');
        amount[0].value = parseInt(amount[0].value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "")).toFixed(0);
    }
</script>

<input type="text" name="amount" value="N50,000.00 NGN" />
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="doWork();">
```

Answer (score -2):

You're skipping over the decimal. Use:

```
if (!isNaN(str[i]) || str[i]=='.')
```

Comment: I don't think OP wants what's after the decimal (expecting 50000). You could stop at the decimal character instead.